# Toys R Us - Frankenstein (Oct 29, 2016)

Tags: instructions

Anyone have a copy of the instructions for the Toys R Us - Frankenstein figure that they gave away on Saturday, Oct. 29, 2016? I attempted to visit the store but the line was wrapped and they ran out. Was hoping to get a copy of the instructions and build requirement to build on my own.

Thanks!

Comment: You might also enjoy [this youtube of one going together](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sp_5qssHDI4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got these from a helpful friend over at BrickPicker.com:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the upload! And sharing the site, I will have to check them out.